# How can I know to which IP address the was made a request if I have configured an ESP device as AP+STA mode

Tags: webserver, esp8266wifi

how are you?. I need to make a web server in a STA+AP mode and I need to open a specific web page only if the server accessed is the one in AP mode, and another page only if the server was accessed using the STA mode, what method of AsyncWebServer request could work for that?.

Until now all the examples that I found opens the same page if the page is accessed in both modes.

thanks in advance for the help.